# Can I delete pointers in destructor when stored in std::vector property?

Tags: c++

I don't want to use smart pointers.

Her'es my code.

```
CCOLFile *pCOLFile = CCOLManager::getInstance()->parseFile(strCOLPath); // returns instance of CCOLFile
// ...
pCOLFile->unload(); // hoping to comment this out, and use destructor instead.
delete pCOLFile;

struct CCOLFile
{
    std::string                     m_strFilePath;
    std::vector<CCOLEntry*>         m_vecEntries;
};

void                CCOLFile::unload(void)
{
    for (auto pCOLEntry : m_vecEntries)
    {
        delete pCOLEntry;
    }
    m_vecEntries.clear();
}
```

Is it safe in c++ to comment my call to CCOLFile::unload, and then move the code from the CCOLFile::unload method to the CCOLFile destructor?

Comment: Probably, but then you have to worry about copy and assignment (look up *the rule of three*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

The whole point of the destructor is to allow you to clean up your object before its memory is freed. So all members are accessible just as they would be in a normal method.

Just be wary not to throw an exception from the destructor, and be careful about getting the memory semantics (copy constructors, assignment, etc.) right in all cases so that nothing is leaked or double-freed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - see [C++ Super-FAQ section on Destructors](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors).

However if you do move that code to the dtor, or have the dtor call unload(), you need to make sure your 'delete pCOLEntry' doesn't throw exceptions. Reason: if it did, and if your CCOLFile dtor got called because of stack-unwinding, you will end up with an exception within an exception; bang; do not do that.

Another problem if 'delete pCOLEntry' can throw an exception: your unload() method will end up with gobbledegook in your CCOLFile object. In particular, only some of the pCOLEntry pointers will have been deleted and they will now point to the carcass of what was once a CCOLEntry object but is now just a ghost. I called that a "Ghost Pointer" in the C++ FAQ. It's a bad thing since you will perhaps in the future use that Ghost Pointer, then you'll end up with a "Wild Pointer." Badness ensues.

Lots of other issues with your code: since you have avoided using a smart-pointer (why?) you really ought to wrap your usage in a try/catch block, or at least put BIG FAT UGLY COMMENTS in your code to make sure no one ever does anything that might throw an exception. Basically if anything throws an exception before control-flow reaches your unload() or 'delete' call, all the CCOLEntry objects will leak and perhaps more significantly any desirable side effects in their dtor will not happen - closing files, unlocking locks, whatever. Note: I'm not asking you whether your code can CURRENTLY throw an exception in that area - that is only a small part of the concern. The concern is not just the present but the future. Someone else (likely at 3am) will add some code somewhere in there and that code will be able to throw an exception. Smart pointers make that innocuous, or a BIG FAT UGLY COMMENT at least makes it slightly less likely.

Another consideration: you need to be concerned with 'ownership' and the copy-constructor and assignment-operator. The [Rule of Three (which I coined in 1991, but which has been more recently been replaced by the Rule of Five or even better the Rule of Zero)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) tells you you will need all of them if you explicitly define one of them, in this case the dtor. Here again a smart-pointer would likely help.

Another thing: your use of (void), e.g., in the definition of CCOLFile::unload(void)) is considered by at least some as an abomination :-) :-) :-)

Comment: I won't be throwing exceptions anywhere in the code and I am the only developer on the project. I am avoiding smart pointers as I will look into them in the future, looking for a solution without them for now. Thanks for all your info, very useful.